# Ubuntu 12.04 boots to command line after upgrade

Tags: boot, command-line, nvidia

Today package manager suggested the usual updates and I installed everything. After it prompted for reboot, Ubuntu restarted in command line mode. Not sure what to do here. By browsing the forum it seems as though this might have to do with NVIDIA drivers. I tried "startx" (black screen with flashing cursor on top left), and Ctrl-Alt-F1 (nothing happens). I also tried to reboot in failsafeX graphic mode but I get the following error:
Fatal Server Error
No screens found
Server terminated with errors

Not sure where to go from here.
I need to get back in graphical mode ASAP and I'm OK with a faster solution even w/o NVIDIA drivers.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: just clarifying that a) I can log on from terminal and b) I am assuming this is an Nvidia issue but have no certainty.

Comment: Try re-installing the nvidia drivers.

Comment: Already tried to no avail

Comment: Tried different drivers from the NVIDIA site and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Tried different drivers from the NVIDIA site and that fixed the issue.
EDIT to provide more detail:
Drivers downloaded from NVIDIA site [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
Just picked my card and Linux version of drivers.
Then from command line I executed:

```
sudo service lightdm stop

sudo sh drivername.run
```

Followed driver instructions

```
sudo service lightdm start
```